# How to distinguish between two equally named folders when loading resources from it? (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath, classloader

The goal is to list all .properties file names in a specified folder and then do something with it. The first part is what I have trouble with due to the fact that the folders have the same names.

Our *MAVEN* project in *eclipse* has the following structure:

```
SubProject_A
      |-src
        |-main
          |-resources
            |-someFolder                     //folder name is the same as in Subproject_B
              |-someResourceBundle.properties
              |-someResourceBundle.properties
SubProject_B
      |-src
        |-main
          |-resources
            |-someFolder                   //folder name is the same as in Subproject_A
              |-someResourceBundle.properties
              |-someResourceBundle.properties
```

---

Whenever I call (listAllResourceFilesInFolder() - see below) the files in the folder of Subproject_A will get listed. I don't know how to specify the equally named folder in Subproject_B? Is it possible that only the folder in subproject_A is on the classpath (or at least occurs at first). How would I solve this problem most elegantly?

Only the folder name is passed as the argument. Is there a way to specify the full path, like */Subproject_A/src/main/resources/someFolder*

```
listAllResourceFilesInFolder("someFolder")
```

Methods lists all available resource file names in folder

```
private static Set<String> listAllResourceFilesInFolder(String folderName) throws IOException {
    Set<String> filenames = new HashSet<>();
try (
        InputStream in = getResourceAsStream(folderName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
    String resource;

    while ((resource = br.readLine()) != null) {
        filenames.add(resource);
    }
}

return filenames;
}

private static InputStream getResourceAsStream(String resource) {
final InputStream in = getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resource);

return in == null ? thisClass.class.getResourceAsStream(resource) : in;
}

private static ClassLoader getContextClassLoader() {
    return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
}
```

Comment: How do you think you could, in theory, handle it? You end up with two files, having the same name, at the same location in the JAR.

Comment: Also, what makes you think that reading a folder resource will return file names? It won't work as soon as you package your code in a jar file. And it's an undocumented feature if not in a jar file.

Comment: @Tunaki: Only the folders are equal, the files do have different names. In the end my idea was that the properties files are in the classpath. I thought about implementing a custom classloader with its own classpath where I can only add the folders/files I'm interested in. But I'm not sure if this is how things work.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Do you mean reading the files does only work at compile time? Isn't there any directory structure in a jar file? I use the class for a JUnit test.

Comment: There is a directory structure, but reading a folder as if it was a text file containing file names just won't work. Just test it.